# Tags usage in Struts 2

Tags: struts2, jsp-tags

I have the following code snippet

```
<s:iterator status="stat" value="masterAccountList">
                <tr>
                  <td><s:property value="name"/></td>
                  <td><s:property value="status"/></td>
                 <s:set name="DrStat" id="DrStat" value="<s:property value='status'/>"/>
                  <td><s:if test='DrStat.contains("Out")'>
                      Dr. Is Available
                      </s:if>
                      <s:else>
                      Dr. Is not Available
                      </s:else>
                  </td>
                </tr>
            </s:iterator>
```

I need to check the status if it contains a keyword and display text accordingly. When I try this, I always get 'Not Available' status.

I'm not even sure what the set returns, how can I see that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution:

```
<s:if test="%{DrStat.contains('Out')}">
```

Work fine. Thanks Dustin.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't `<s:text name="DrStat" />` print the value?

Comment: it just prints "DrStat" in all the cells, nothing else :(

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to do the above from memory.  It is actually <s:property ... />.

There is an example on the Struts 2 tag libs: http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/set.html.

Also you might change 'name' to 'var' per this same page.

Comment: I'm trying it, but I get an error "Attribute var invalid for tag set according to TLD". Any examples?